# What can I deduce from the char a of a field?

Tags: field-theory

I've a homework question, stating: Let $F$ be a field with the addition and multiplication operation such that $\mathrm{char}(F)=2$. For $a,b\in F$, prove that $a + b = a-b$.

I know that $\mathrm{char}(F)=2$ means that for $F, 1+1 = 0$, but I can't see how that helps me to solve the problem.

Can I assume that $a,b$ must be $0$ or $1$? I think that's wrong. What else can I deduce that'll help me?

Comment: What is $b+b$ ?

Comment: b+b = b(1+1) = b*0 = 0

Comment: So what is the relationship between $b$ and $-b$ ?

Comment: if b is the additive negation element of b (i.e. the element such that a+a = 0) then b = -b

Comment: Note $\ a+b = a-b\iff b = -b \iff 0 = b+b  = b(1\!+\!1)\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a+b+b=a+b(1+1)=a+b\cdot 0=a$$
Therefore
$$a+b=a-b$$